Difference between .scalars().all() and list(...scalars()) in SQLAlchemy
Are there any significant differences (performance, or otherwise) between the following two ways of getting a list of results?
users: Sequence[User] = session.execute(select(User)).scalars().all()

users: Sequence[User] = list(session.execute(select(User)).scalars())

The second seems more pythonic to me, and is possible because ScalarResult is iterable over its rows, so calling list(...scalars()) just iterates over the ScalarResult object. However, since .all() also exists, I assume there must be some reason for it, so maybe it's more efficient to use .all()?
What are the differences between the two, and what, if anything, goes on behind the scenes that causes the difference?

Asked and answered on GitHub here

Through looking at the source, it seems there is a difference. Calling ScalarResult.all() it eventually calls ResultInternal._allrows().Meanwhile ScalarResult.__iter__() (which list() is internally calling) it eventually calls ResultInternal._iterator_getter().
While there might at first seem to be a lot of duplication between these methods, there's one key difference: .all() is fetching the results in one shot, while .__iter__() is streaming in results one-by-one.
The iterator method can be useful in times where you might need to short circuit and know you don't need the full result set. But this example is kinda squandering that.
In terms of performance, there's a lot of layers in-between so that's harder to comment on. But in terms of using SQLAlchemy, I would say .all() is preferable for this use-case.
